# How to access struct inside module where struct defined [Elixir]

Tags: elixir

I'm in the very beginning of learning Elixir, but have a programming background with several OOP languages, mostly Ruby. I found example how I can define struct inside module:

```
defmodule Example.User do
  defstruct name: "Sean", roles: []
end
```

Also, I found I can set this value when I  create structs:
`steve = %Example.User{name: "Steve", roles: [:admin, :owner]}`
and can access it outside module just by calling  `steve.name`

The question is, how can I access struct data INSIDE module, so let's say I want to access **name** field from **call_my_name** function:

```
defmodule Example.User do
  defstruct name: ""
  def call_my_name do
     IO.write(???)
  end 
end
martin = %Example.User{name: "Martin"}
```

In terms of OOP, I just trying to write a *getter*.

How can I do it? What is a good/default way to do it? If I can't, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the syntax might look similar to Ruby at first, Elixir is *not* an OOP language. You don't have "methods" in Elixir. Instead, you need to explicitly call the function and pass in the struct:

```
defmodule Example.User do
  defstruct name: ""

  def call_my_name(%Example.User{name: name}) do
     IO.write(name)
  end 
end

martin = %Example.User{name: "Martin"}
Example.User.call_my_name(martin)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I really appreciate it. I understand it's not about OOP, I just want to clarify a few things . What is good/default method to combine data and related actions? Should I just define struct and  functions inside a module so I can pass the struct to this functions? Is any exact concept/idea why I can't access data inside?

Comment: @YarTheGreat The approach of creating structs and functions to "modify" those structs makes sense. But try not to thing of structs as objects. I put _modify_ between quotes, because in a functional language you don't modify the data, you merely create a copy of the original data with the modification.

Comment: Hey, can you also explain this function declaration, why can  we declare argument like that: "call_my_name(%Example.User{name: name})" Or give me a source when I can read about this form? It reminds me static style declaration while we using dynamic language. Is this form of guard or what? Never seen it before.

Comment: @YarTheGreat it's pattern matching, sort of similar to a guard in that the next function definition is tried if this one fails. That specific one is pattern matching on structs. See http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html for more info about pattern matching and http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html for an example of pattern matching with structs.

Comment: maybe the function name could be confusing (for those who see it in the future): `call_my_name` can be `call_name` better here, it will show there are no bindings between the struct and the functions. modules are just a namespace, and we are just defining functions and structs in the same area. You can call `Example.User.call_name/1` for any kind of data. (But yes you need to pass the pattern matching in the example above)

Answer (score 11):

Just to pile on here, you don't need to use the full namespace within your own module, so long as you don't have another User module to reference. Try this:

```
defmodule Example.User do
  alias __MODULE__ # <- this is the magic

  defstruct [:name]

  def my_fun(%User{} = user)
    IO.inspect(user)
  end
end
```

Thanks to https://dockyard.com/blog/2017/08/15/elixir-tips for the tip

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but I will include a more idiomatic answer to remind people that you don't need to alias the current module (it is already "aliased").  You can, however, make good use of the `__MODULE__` macro to expand to the full module name.  The trick is that this can also be used to reference the struct of the same name:

```
defmodule Example.User do
  defstruct name: ""

  def call_my_name(%__MODULE__{name: name}) do
     IO.write(name)
  end 
end
```

For good measure, we can look at this the other way around and see how to view the module name from a given struct. Remember that structs are maps -- they have a secret `:__struct__` key which contains the module name which defined them.

```
iex> d = DateTime.utc_now()
~U[2022-05-11 13:22:41.751959Z]
iex> Map.get(d, :__struct__)
DateTime
```

Comment: no, that's giving a `(CompileError) Example.User.Example.User.__struct__/0 is undefined, cannot expand struct`. Just this `alias __MODULE__` from Michael works.

Comment: I think you have mis-copied something (or perhaps used an alias improperly?) because you have duplication in your module name: `Example.User.Example.User`.  Not sure if that merited a downvote.

Comment: the error was like this in the console, with the duplicated module name.

Comment: I can't reproduce that, so perhaps you need to include the full code that causes the error.  Like I said, I think you may have mis-copied something or used an improper alias.